# When migrating to Material-UI v5, how to deal with conditional classes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the [official migration guide](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#main-content), they give the following example of changing the code from JSS (`makeStyles`) to the new `styled` mode.

Before:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    background: theme.palette.primary.main,
}));

function Component() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <div className={classes.root} />
}
```

After:

```
const MyComponent = styled('div')(({ theme }) => 
    ({ background: theme.palette.primary.main }));

function App(props) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MyComponent {...props} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

This is fine for a single class, but what to do when the code has conditional classes?

e.g.

```
<main className={classnames(content, open ? contentOpen : contentClosed)}>
    {/* content goes here */}
</main>
```

Here, `content`, `contentOpen`, and `contentClosed` are classes returned from `useStyles`, but `contentOpen` and `contentClosed` are rendered conditionally based on the value of `open`.

With the new `styled` method, instead of generating class names we're generating components. Is there a way to elegantly replicate the rendering without resorting to content duplication in the ternary expression?

e.g. we **don't** want to do something like:

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {open
            ? <MyOpenComponent {...props}>{/* content */}</MyOpenComponent>
            : <MyClosedComponent {...props}>{/* content */}</MyClosedComponent>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few possible ways to deal with this. One approach using `styled` is to leverage props to do dynamic styles rather than trying to use multiple classes.

Here's an example:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledDiv = styled("div")(({ open, theme }) => {
  const color = open
    ? theme.palette.primary.contrastText
    : theme.palette.secondary.contrastText;
  return {
    backgroundColor: open
      ? theme.palette.primary.main
      : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    color,
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    "& button": {
      color
    }
  };
});

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <StyledDiv open={open}>
      <h1>{open ? "Open" : "Closed"}</h1>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Toggle</Button>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit replacing multiple makeStyles classes in v5]

Here's an equivalent example using TypeScript:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledDiv: React.ComponentType<{ open: boolean }> = styled("div")(
  ({ open, theme }) => {
    const color = open
      ? theme.palette.primary.contrastText
      : theme.palette.secondary.contrastText;
    return {
      backgroundColor: open
        ? theme.palette.primary.main
        : theme.palette.secondary.main,
      color,
      padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
      "& button": {
        color
      }
    };
  }
);

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <StyledDiv open={open}>
      <h1>{open ? "Open" : "Closed"}</h1>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Toggle</Button>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit replacing multiple makeStyles classes in v5]

Some other possible approaches:

- Use Emotion's `css` prop and Emotion's capabilities for [composing styles](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition)
- Use [tss-react](https://github.com/garronej/tss-react) to retain similar syntax to `makeStyles` but backed by Emotion (so you wouldn't be including both Emotion and JSS in your bundle as would be the case if you leverage `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/styles`). This is the route I took when migrating to v5 and as part of my migration I created a [codemod](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/#2-use-tss-react) for migrating JSS `makeStyles` to tss-react's `makeStyles`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll add another remark that someone may find useful: since the function passed to `styled(Component)(() => { /*...*/ })` runs at render time, we can call hooks inside. So we can access the Context API in this function.

Comment: Great answer! I wonder if there is also a TypeScript example. I can't figure out the typing to allow passing things like `open` to the styled component.

Comment: @JaanusVarus I've added a TypeScript example

Comment: This is shorter in typescript: `styled("div")<YourProps>(...)`. There is no need to declare `React.ComponentType` here.