# Using conditional styles in Material-UI with styled vs JSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, emotion

I'm using Material-UI v5 and trying to migrate to using `styled` instead of `makeStyles` because it seems as though that's the "preferred" approach now. I understand using `makeStyles` is still valid but I'm trying to embrace the new styling solution instead.

I've got a list of list items which represent navigation links, and I want to highlight the one that's currently selected. Here's how I did this using `makeStyles`:

```
interface ListItemLinkProps {
    label: string;
    to: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme>(theme => ({
    selected: {
        color: () => theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
}));

const ListItemLink = ({ to, label, children }: PropsWithChildren<ListItemLinkProps>) => {
    const styles = useStyles();

    const match = useRouteMatch(to);
    const className = clsx({ [styles.selected]: !!match });

    return (
        <ListItem button component={Link} to={to} className={className}>
            <ListItemIcon>{children}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={label} />
        </ListItem>
    );
};
```

*(Note here I'm using [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) to determine if the `selected` style should be applied to the `ListItem` element.)*

How do I achieve this using `styled`? This is what I've come up with so far (note: the interface for `ListItemLinkProps` hasn't changed so I haven't repeated it here):

```
const LinkItem = styled(ListItem, {
    shouldForwardProp: (propName: PropertyKey) => propName !== 'isSelected'
})<ListItemProps & LinkProps & { isSelected: boolean }>(({ theme, isSelected }) => ({
    ...(isSelected && { color: theme.palette.primary.main }),
}));

const ListItemLink = ({ to, label, children }: PropsWithChildren<ListItemLinkProps>) => {
    const match = useRouteMatch(to);

    return (
        // @ts-ignore
        <LinkItem button component={Link} to={to} isSelected={!!match}>
            <ListItemIcon>{children}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={label} />
        </LinkItem>
    );
};
```

So, two questions about this:

1. Is this best way to do a conditional style?
2. The other problem is that I can't work out the correct types for the `styled` declaration - I have to put the `// @ts-ignore` comment above the `LinkItem` because of the way its types are declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Material-UI v5 uses Emotion for the default style engine and consistently uses `styled` internally in order to make it easier for people who want to use styled-components instead of Emotion to not have to include both in the bundle.

Though the `styled` API works fine for a lot of use cases, it seems like a clumsy fit for this particular use case. There are two main options that provide a considerably better DX.

One option is to use the new [sx prop](https://next.material-ui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) available on all Material-UI components (and the [Box component](https://next.material-ui.com/system/box/) can be used to wrap non-MUI components to access the `sx` features). Below is a modification of [one of the List demos](https://next.material-ui.com/components/lists/#selected-listitem) demonstrating this approach (with the custom `ListItemButton` simulating the role of your `ListItemLink`):

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import MuiListItemButton, {
  ListItemButtonProps
} from "@material-ui/core/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";

const ListItemButton = ({
  selected = false,
  ...other
}: ListItemButtonProps) => {
  const match = selected;
  return (
    <MuiListItemButton
      {...other}
      sx={{ color: match ? "primary.main" : undefined }}
    />
  );
};
export default function SelectedListItem() {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
    index: number
  ) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 0}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 1}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DraftsIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folder">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 2}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 3}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 3)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit SelectedListItem Material Demo]

The only downside of this approach is that it is currently [notably slower](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/#performance-tradeoff) than using `styled`, but it is still fast enough to be fine for most use cases.

The other option is to use Emotion directly via its [css prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop). This allows a similar DX (though not quite as convenient use of the theme), but without any performance penalty.

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import MuiListItemButton, {
  ListItemButtonProps
} from "@material-ui/core/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const ListItemButton = ({
  selected = false,
  ...other
}: ListItemButtonProps) => {
  const match = selected;
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <MuiListItemButton
      {...other}
      css={css({ color: match ? theme.palette.primary.main : undefined })}
    />
  );
};
export default function SelectedListItem() {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
    index: number
  ) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 0}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 1}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DraftsIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folder">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 2}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 3}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 3)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit SelectedListItem Material Demo]

In the app I work on (which I haven't yet started to migrate to v5), I expect to use a combination of `styled` and Emotion's `css` function/prop. I'm hesitant to use the `sx` prop heavily until its performance improves a bit (which I think will happen eventually). Even though it performs "fast enough" for many cases, when I have two options with similar DX available and one is twice as fast as the other, I find it difficult to opt for the slower one. The main cases where I would opt for the `sx` prop are for components where I want to set CSS properties differently for different breakpoints or similar areas where the `sx` prop provides much nicer DX than other options.

Related answers:

- [Is there a performance difference between the sx prop and the makeStyles function in Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68383046/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-the-sx-prop-and-the-makestyles-functio/68383383#68383383)
- [When migrating to Material-UI v5, how to deal with conditional classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471759/when-migrating-to-material-ui-v5-how-to-deal-with-conditional-classes/68472931#68472931)

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Helpful as I've just migrated to V5 with gradual migration mods. Some changes during migration: `breakpoints`, `overrides` and  `CSS Class name changes`

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me with using sx

```
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

...

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(useTheme().breakpoints.down('md'));
```

...

```
<Divider sx={{ whiteSpace: isMobile ? 'normal' : 'pre'}}>
```